# VSCode CMake Not Linking Package

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm trying to create a project using OpenCV in VS Code and I'm having an issue where the included header is not being detected despite no issues occurring with CMake. My CMake code is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ASCII VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "C:/opencv")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable( ASCII main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( ASCII ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

My main.cpp file is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{

    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/Vivek/lenna.png");
    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
main.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp': No such file or directory
```

This is my first time working with CMake, so I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. It doesn't throw any errors with CMake itself, only when I try to run main.

Comment: Can you have a look at the include directories in your project settings in VS Code? Probably this will give you more insights?

Comment: This might be off topic, but it's clear from the error message that you are compiling with Visual Studio. Yet your development environment includes two other major tools, VSCode and CMake. Have you considered just using Visual Studio? Wouldn't that be simpler? What benefit are you getting from these extra tools? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, that the `include_directories` is pointing to unexpected content.

You could add this after the `include_directories` call in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
message(
"OpenCV package:
    found: ${OpenCV_FOUND}
    include dir: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}"
)
```

and look at the printed `include dir:` . The directory it is pointing to, should contain a structure like `opencv2\opencv.hpp`.

P.S.: I tried your code with the `OpenCV – 4.6.0` release with the windows-release package and the build worked.